# Getting error "Error loading private server key"

Tags: ssl, fiware-orion, fiware

So I was implementing rush in Orion Context Broker Server instance, and whenever I try to start the contextBroker with the following command:

```
contextBroker -rush localhost:1234 -https -key privkey.pem -cert cert.csr
```

, I'm getting the following error:

```
 E@18:16:11  loadFile[1101]: error opening 'privkey.pem': No such file or directory
 X@18:16:11  main[1258]: Error loading private server key from 'privkey.pem'
```

I generated my private key with the following command, I don't know if it's correct:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out privkey.pem 2048
```

And I generated my certificate with the following command:

```
openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -out cert.csr
```

Do I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use absolute path names, i.e.:

```
contextBroker -rush localhost:1234 -https -key /path/to/privkey.pem -cert /path/to/cert.csr
```

A note has been added to [CLI commands documenation](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Command_line_options) to make this clearer.

In addition, you may find useful [the following script](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/scripts/httpsPrepare.sh) on how to generate the needed files:

```
...
openssl genrsa -out "$keyFileName" 1024 > /dev/null 2>&1
openssl req -days 365 -out "$certFileName" -new -x509 -key "$keyFileName" -subj "$OPTIONS" > /dev/null 2>&1
```