# How to make rush work with my orionInstance

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

Following my previous question [How to show an entity from OrionContextBroker in the MapViewer widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111916/how-to-show-an-entity-from-orioncontextbroker-in-the-mapviewer-widget) I configured my context broker instance using Rush and I am using https://ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org as NGSI proxy.

I start the orionContextBroker instance like this: ***contextBroker -rush localhost:5001*** and everything seems to be working correctly (I can insert/query data etc), but when the MapViewerWidget gets loaded I get this message from the OrionInstance log:

```
INFO@17:32:53  clientSocketHttp.cpp[152]: Starting transaction to ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org:443/callbacks/19:32:59-1:19:33:01-1
WARNING@17:32:53  clientSocketHttp.cpp[342]: Notification failure for localhost:5001 (curl_easy_perform failed: Couldn't connect to server)
INFO@17:32:53  clientSocketHttp.cpp[359]: Transaction ended
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your [Rush](https://github.com/telefonicaid/Rush) installation, it should be running at `localhost:5001` (your context broker cannot connect to it).

See the ["Using Rush relayer"](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/rush/index.html) and the ["Security consideration"](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/security/index.html) sections for more information. You can also take a look to the responses to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177105/getting-error-error-loading-private-server-key).

Comment: I've updated the question with the new configuration!

Comment: @JoseCastillo your context broker instance cannot start because another process is listening on port 1026. Check the context broker is not already running (ps aux | grep contextBroker).

Comment: there is not any instance already running, neither any process listening on port 1026 :/ i've updated the question! and thnks for the help!!

Comment: @JoseCastillo please, try again without using the https flags: `-https`, `-k` and `-cert`. You don't need it for using the integration with Rush and may be the source of the problem.

Comment: Alvaro it is working! Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it.