# Rush not working on my Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I have deployed an Orion Context Broker v0.20.0 instance using AWS. I'm trying to show an entity from it on the MapViewer widget of the Fiware Lab Wirecloud Mashup.

It seems like I'm having some kind of trouble with the NGSI source operator. I have configured it with:

- NGSI server URL: http://MyORionInstanceIP:1026
- NGSI proxy URL: https://ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org (I have also tried ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org)

I run my Conntext broker instance like this: ***contextBroker -port 1026 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker -pidpath /var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost localhost -db orion -t 0-255 -rush localhost:5001***, and it works, but when I accept the operator configuration to create the subscription, this is what I read on my Context Broker:

```
DEBUG@12:07:40  senderThread.cpp[47]: sending to: host='ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org', port=443, verb=POST, tenant='', service-path: '', xauthToken: '', path='/callbacks/14:27:47-1:15:08:34-1', content-type: application/xml
DEBUG@12:07:40  sem.cpp[124]: transactionIdSet taking the 'trans' semaphore for 'changing the transaction id'
DEBUG@12:07:40  sem.cpp[126]: transactionIdSet has the 'trans' semaphore
DEBUG@12:07:40  sem.cpp[181]: transactionIdSet gives the 'trans' semaphore for 'changing the transaction id'
INFO@12:07:40  clientSocketHttp.cpp[154]: Starting transaction to ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org:443/callbacks/14:27:47-1:15:08:34-1
DEBUG@12:07:40  clientSocketHttp.cpp[240]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'X-relayer-host: ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org:443'
DEBUG@12:07:40  clientSocketHttp.cpp[247]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'X-relayer-protocol: https'
DEBUG@12:07:40  clientSocketHttp.cpp[260]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'User-Agent: orion/0.20.0 libcurl/7.19.7'
DEBUG@12:07:40  clientSocketHttp.cpp[268]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'Host: localhost:5001'
DEBUG@12:07:40  clientSocketHttp.cpp[305]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'Content-length: 1141'
DEBUG@12:07:40  clientSocketHttp.cpp[353]: Sending message 18 to HTTP server: sending message of 1370 bytes to HTTP server
WARNING@12:07:40  clientSocketHttp.cpp[358]: Notification failure for localhost:5001 (curl_easy_perform failed: Couldn't connect to server)
INFO@12:07:40  clientSocketHttp.cpp[375]: Transaction ended
```

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255831/how-to-make-rush-work-with-my-orioninstance), but it hasn't solved my problem so far, neither the Orion documentation.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**EDIT:**

It looks like that rush wasn't event installed, so I did it.

But everytime I try to run the listener it gives me this error:

```
time=2015-05-07T13:56:17.331Z | lvl=ERROR | op=RESPUSH BUCKET TASKS | msg=Error getting bucket elements | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | hostname=***** | component=retryBuckets | error=[Error: ERR unknown command 'evalsha']
```

Now, when I accept the operator, this are the traces:

*-ORION:*

```
DEBUG@15:04:28  senderThread.cpp[47]: sending to: host='ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org', port=443, verb=POST, tenant='', service-path: '', xauthToken: '', path='/callbacks/13:35:20-1:18:05:22-1', content-type: application/xml
DEBUG@15:04:28  sem.cpp[124]: transactionIdSet taking the 'trans' semaphore for 'changing the transaction id'
DEBUG@15:04:28  sem.cpp[126]: transactionIdSet has the 'trans' semaphore
DEBUG@15:04:28  sem.cpp[181]: transactionIdSet gives the 'trans' semaphore for 'changing the transaction id'
INFO@15:04:28  clientSocketHttp.cpp[154]: Starting transaction to ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org:443/callbacks/13:35:20-1:18:05:22-1
DEBUG@15:04:28  clientSocketHttp.cpp[240]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'X-relayer-host: ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org:443'
DEBUG@15:04:28  clientSocketHttp.cpp[247]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'X-relayer-protocol: https'
DEBUG@15:04:28  clientSocketHttp.cpp[260]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'User-Agent: orion/0.20.0 libcurl/7.19.7'
DEBUG@15:04:28  clientSocketHttp.cpp[268]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'Host: localhost:5001'
DEBUG@15:04:28  clientSocketHttp.cpp[305]: HTTP-HEADERS: 'Content-length: 1141'
DEBUG@15:04:28  clientSocketHttp.cpp[353]: Sending message 1 to HTTP server: sending message of 1370 bytes to HTTP server
INFO@15:04:28  clientSocketHttp.cpp[364]: Notification Successfully Sent to localhost:5001/callbacks/13:35:20-1:18:05:22-1
INFO@15:04:28  clientSocketHttp.cpp[375]: Transaction ended
```

*-Listener:*

```
time=2015-05-07T15:08:12.803Z | lvl=INFO | op=RELAY REQUEST | msg=Relay Request received | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | hostname=Orion-Njoy | component=listener | userID='127.0.0.1' | reqInfo={ url: '/callbacks/13:35:20-1:18:09:06-1',  method: 'POST',  remoteAddress: '127.0.0.1',  headers:    { 'x-relayer-host': 'ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org:443',     'x-relayer-protocol': 'https',     'x-relayer-proxy': undefined,     'x-relayer-retry': undefined,     'x-relayer-httpcallback': undefined,     'x-relayer-persistence': undefined,     'x-relayer-traceid': undefined,     'x-relayer-encoding': undefined,     'content-type': 'application/xml' },  responseTime: 1,  statusCode: 500,  bodyLength: 1141,  id:    { exceptionId: 'SVR1000',     exceptionText: 'Generic Server Error: Error: ERR unknown command \'evalsha\'' } }
time=2015-05-07T15:08:12.803Z | lvl=INFO | op=PERSISTENCE | msg=Persistence Completed | corr=N/A | trans=e1467620-f4ca-11e4-a50f-ebe0dffc0e2e | hostname=Orion-Njoy | component=evPersistence | userID='127.0.0.1' | state='error'
```

*-Consumer:*

```
time=2015-05-07T13:56:17.331Z | lvl=ERROR | op=RESPUSH BUCKET TASKS | msg=Error getting bucket elements | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | hostname=Orion-Njoy | component=retryBuckets | error=[Error: ERR unknown command 'evalsha']
```

Any ideas, please?

**EDIT 2:**

I've manage to get it working thanks to the responses. The problem was that I was using redis 2.4, and it's required the 2.6 or supperior version. Now I can see my entities in the Map Viewer.

In case someone runs with the same problem, don't forget to [install Rush](https://github.com/telefonicaid/Rush/wiki) and follow this [instructions](http://codingsteps.com/install-redis-2-6-on-amazon-ec2-linux-ami-or-centos/) to install Redis 2.6:

Thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the redis version is too old. EVAL/EVALSHA commands were introduced in redis 2.6.
I would check the redis version (>2.6.0)

Comment: You are right. That was the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the broker is unable to connect to rush, running in the same host and accepting connections on port 5001.
Are you sure rush is running? (and that it is on port 5001?).
The broker doesn't implement notifications (yet) in https itself, but needs rush for this purpose. But of course, rush must be running for this to work ...

Comment: Well, I was kinda lost with all the "Rush" thing and, of course, it wasn't even installed. I have updated the question with the new scenario.